# Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring-webflow

I am really having a problem about what to use as an alternative for web flow. I have read that not all functionalities should be handled by web flow. Only those which needs complex xstate management. For those easy stuffs like just login, editing or deleting records what will I use as an alternative for web flow?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Web flow is specifically designed to implement complex page flows. It is an extension of Spring MVC and a tool to specify page navigation rules and manage navigation.

Spring Web flow provides fundamental answers to the following major problems in web application development:

How to specify page navigation rules?
How to manage navigation and conversational state?
How to ensure modularity and code reuse?

It is also integrated with JSF component model and used mostly for enterprise application development. There are not so many alternatives but but for Vaadin component model you can consider [Lexaden Web Flow](http://www.lexaden.com/main/entry/web_flow) as possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

How did you build websites before Web Flow?

My understanding is that if something needs "back" functionality that has state information stored - like a "wizard", for example - Web Flow is the way to go.  If you don't have state, I'd expect you'd build those pages as you always have.

Comment: Currently that is where I am having a problem with. I am implementing an edit functionality with validation. The thing is when my validation for the username and old password if it exists and validation for new password and confirm password if they are equal,if either of them fails, when I return it to the view state which displays again the form with initial username value I get null pointer exceptions